# Pandas row in df.iterrows() returns pandas series where as string was expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am iterating over two pandas dataframes in the following way

```
for index1, row_ds1 in ds1.iterrows():
     for index2, row_ds2 in ds2.iterrows():
           print([type(row_ds1['colA']), type(row_ds1['colB']),type( row_ds2['colX']), type(row_ds2['colY'])])
```

## output

```
[<class 'str'>, <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>, <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>, <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>]
```

The first element of the list is a string as expected but the others are pandas series and I don't understand why it returns a pandas series. I have studied and tried myself manually so it returns normal string but when I run like on the original dataset it returns pandas series.

Comment: Can you show some of the dataframes to make it easier to troubleshoot?

Comment: I cannot put the original dataset as it contains hundreds of columns but I tried the same with few columns and it was working fine and returning strings but with large dataset it was returning pandas series.

Comment: You must have columns with the same name in you hundreds of columns

Comment: There really isn't anything wrong with the syntax on your code, I think something is off with the data you are inputting